# Twitter tweet event binding/rebinding

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter

I have a dynamic content for which i want a customize tweet description I have taken help from [This](https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet) link, I am calling code in my aspx page like below

```
html = "<a href='https://twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button' data-url='" + url + "' data-text='" + imagedesc + "' data-via='test' data-hashtags='mytag1,mytag2'></a>";
$(ctrl).append(html);
twttr.widgets.load();

twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) {

 //do something here

});
```

This code is calling perfectly first time but when i call this 2nd time it will not executing callback method after tweet, someone suggested to unbind the event like this 'twttr.events.unbind('tweet')' but this solution is not working. I have a dynamic content to share plz suggest something helpful

Answer (score 1):

Every time you bind a function to the tweet event, it will add that function to a handler collection. When a tweet occurs, it should execute each function added to the handler collection.

After you bind the 2nd event, try executing the line below in the Chrome Dev Tools console. It should display all the functions binded to the tweet event.

```
> twttr.events._handlers.tweet
```